# Rancher:Failed to communicate with API server during namespace check

Tags: rancher

Here is the cluster error message of rancher.

```
Cluster health check failed: Failed to communicate with API server during namespace check: Get "https://10.100.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system?timeout=45s": context deadline exceeded
```

[image]

I didn't do anything, but it happened by chance. How should I check it

Comment: Hi, check the network latency between rancher pod and downstream k8s api-server ?

Comment: Thank you. It's caused by network delay